# Executing jest tests in angular with a .mjs library

Tags: angular, jestjs, es6-modules

I have an Angular 17 project and want to run my tests with jest.

However, when executing them I receive the error `SyntaxError: Identifier 'exports' has already been declared` for files in my node_modules (`node_modules/@ui5/webcomponents-ngx/fesm2022/ui5-webcomponents-ngx.mjs:266`: `const exports = [...imports];`).

The angular app itself compiles and runs without issues, so it has something to do with my jest setup. But I had no luck yet to make it run. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "jest.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

My `jest.config.ts`:

```
import type {Config} from 'jest';
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest'

const config: Config = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ...pathsToModuleNameMapper({}, {
      prefix: '<rootDir>/'
    }),
    flat: '<rootDir>/node_modules/flat/index.js',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts']
};

export default config;
```

I already tried all combinations of

```
transform: {},
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
moduleNameMapper: {
    ...(stuff from above),
    '^@ui5/(.*)$': '@ui5/$1',
}
```

But I have to confess that these were all wild guesses based on solutions for problems I found online that appeared to be similar, but it always resulted in the same error.